# Calculating an aggregate select statement in SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, select

```
SELECT 
    [ODT].[Date] AS 'ds',
    SUM(CAST([ODT].[Units] AS bigint)) AS 'total',
    SUM(CAST([ODT].[BASE] AS bigint)) AS 'Base',
    SUM(CAST([ODT].[Women] AS bigint)) AS 'Women',
    SUM(CAST([ODT].[Woven] AS bigint)) AS 'Woven',
    SUM(CAST([ODT].[DHLAccessories] AS bigint)) AS 'DHLAccessories',
    SUM(CAST([ODT].[BASE] + [ODT].[Women] + [ODT].[Woven] + [ODT].[DHLAccessories] AS bigint)) AS 'Full'
FROM 
    Orders ODT
```

I am getting all NULLS in the `Full` column where I am expecting to add the above columns

Answer (score 2):

could be you have null issue  so try replace null with 0

```
SELECT [ODT].[Date] as 'ds'

,SUM(CAST( [ODT].[Units] AS bigint)) AS 'total'
,SUM(CAST( [ODT].[BASE] as bigint)) AS 'Base'
,SUM(CAST( [ODT].[Women] as bigint)) AS 'Women'
,SUM(CAST( [ODT].[Woven] as bigint)) AS 'Woven'
,SUM(CAST( [ODT].[DHLAccessories] as bigint)) AS 'DHLAccessories'
,sum(CAST( isnull([ODT].[BASE],0) + isnull([ODT].[Women],0) + isnull([ODT].[Woven],0) + isnull([ODT].[DHLAccessories],0)  as bigint)) as 'Full'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT [ODT].[Date] as 'ds'
  ,SUM(CAST([ODT].[Units] AS bigint)) AS 'total'
    ,SUM(CAST ([ODT].[BASE] as bigint)) AS 'Base'
    ,SUM(CAST ([ODT].[Women] as bigint)) AS 'Women'
    ,SUM(CAST ([ODT].[Woven] as bigint)) AS 'Woven'
    ,SUM(CAST ([ODT].[DHLAccessories] as bigint)) AS 'DHLAccessories'
    ,sum(CAST([ODT].[BASE] as bigint) + CAST([ODT].[Women] as bigint) + 
  CAST([ODT].[Woven] as bigint) + CAST([ODT].[DHLAccessories] as bigint)) as 'Full'
 FROM Orders ODT
```

or

```
SELECT a.*,
    SUM(a.total + a.Base + a.Women + a.Woven + a.DHLAccessories) as 'Full'
FROM (SELECT [ODT].[Date] as 'ds'
      ,SUM(CAST([ODT].[Units] AS bigint)) AS 'total'
        ,SUM(CAST ([ODT].[BASE] as bigint)) AS 'Base'
        ,SUM(CAST ([ODT].[Women] as bigint)) AS 'Women'
        ,SUM(CAST ([ODT].[Woven] as bigint)) AS 'Woven'
        ,SUM(CAST ([ODT].[DHLAccessories] as bigint)) AS 'DHLAccessories'
     FROM Orders ODT) AS a
```

Answer (score 0):

You question has multiple issues.  As a syntax error, you are missing the `GROUP BY`.

In addition, you are overusing escapes.  And using single quotes for column aliases -- neither are recommended and just clutter the query.

And finally, you are not taking `NULL` values into account; I would recommend `COALESCE()` for this:

```
SELECT o.[Date] as ds,
       SUM(CAST(o.units AS bigint)) AS total,
       SUM(CAST(o.BASE as bigint)) AS Base,
       SUM(CAST(o.Women as bigint)) AS Women,
       SUM(CAST(o.Woven as bigint)) AS Woven,
       SUM(CAST(o.DHLAccessories as bigint)) AS DHLAccessories,
       SUM(COALESCE(o.base, 0) + COALESCE(o.Women, 0) +
           COALESCE(o.woven, 0) + coalesce(o.DHLAccessories, 0)
          ) as [Full]
FROM Orders o
GROUP BY o.date;
```

Note that you do need to escape `FULL` because it is a SQL reserved word (think `FULL JOIN`).

Note that the last condition doesn't explicitly convert the values to `bigint`.  I doubt that is needed for the other columns, but I left the conversion in.